# What are gray constraints in Xcode view hierarchy debug view?

Tags: ios, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

I know what the solid ones are: I created them myself. What about the gray ones? Implicit, maybe via size-to-fit? The gray height conflicts with the solid height. Where do the gray ones come from?

[image: screen shot from Xcode]

Comment: Where can I capture this image in storyboard?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are inspecting an object such as a label that has an intrinsic content size. The intrinsic content size generates height and width constraints; that's what intrinsic content size *is*. The constraints in gray are showing you the constraints that the intrinsic content size generates. If you just *look* at them, you can *see* that: they say "content size"!

They are in gray because they are overridden by your explicit constraints (they have a lower priority). But they are still there, and if you were not overriding them, they would take effect (and they would not be gray).

Comment: Thank you, I sorta suspected. Your second paragraph had the vital info I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because I added subviews to UIStackView using addSubview instead of addArrangedSubview. -_-