# Container View's Frame Set to CGRectZero when Using Programmatic Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a `UIView` subclass that will be a tooltip that can appear on the bottom of any view controller to show a hint/error message/success message/etc. The tooltip view has two subviews: a `UILabel` on the left-hand side and a `UIView` on the right hand side, that can be anything (but is often used as a `UIButton`).

**TooltipView.h**

```
@interface TooltipView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *textLabel;

@property (nonatomic) UIView *rightView;
```

**TooltipView.m**

```
static CGFloat const kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing = 7.0f;
static CGFloat const kTextLabelToRightViewHorizontalSpacing = 7.0f;

@implementation TooltipView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        _textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [_textLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self addSubview:_textLabel];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setRightView:(UIView *)rightView {
    if (_rightView != rightView) {
        _rightView = rightView;

        [self addSubview:_rightView];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (BOOL)translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
    return NO;
}

- (void)updateConstraints {
    self.didUpdateConstraints = YES;

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                                      constant:kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing]];

    NSMutableDictionary *metricsDictionary = [@{@"subviewToSuperviewSpacing": @(kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing)} mutableCopy];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewsDictionary = [@{@"textLabel": self.textLabel} mutableCopy];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-subviewToSuperviewSpacing-[textLabel]-subviewToSuperviewSpacing-|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:metricsDictionary
                                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

    if (self.rightView) {
        metricsDictionary[@"textLabelToRightViewHorizontalSpacing"] = @(kTextLabelToRightViewHorizontalSpacing);
        viewsDictionary[@"rightView"] = self.rightView;

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-subviewToSuperviewSpacing-[rightView]-subviewToSuperviewSpacing-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:metricsDictionary
                                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.rightView
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:self
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                        multiplier:1.0f
                                                          constant:kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing]];
    }

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

I also have a view controller to test this with a `UILabel` as the `rightView`. It subclasses `UIViewController`, and its only method is overriding `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView {
    TooltipView *tooltipView = [[TooltipView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    tooltipView.textLabel.text = @"Test 1";

    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    testLabel.text = @"Hello there";
    [testLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    tooltipView.rightView = testLabel;

    self.view = tooltipView;
```

}

Finally, in the view controller where I want to display a tooltip, I add the TooltipViewController as a child view controller. Eventually, this will be triggered by some event, but for testing purposes, I have this being added in `viewWillAppear:`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.aViewController = [[TooltipViewController alloc] init];
    self.aViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self addChildViewController:self.aViewController];

    [self.view addSubview:self.aViewController.view];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:@{@"view": self.aViewController.view}]];

    [self.aViewController.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.aViewController.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                                       constant:150.0f]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.aViewController.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                                       constant:0.0f]];

    [self.aViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

However, at runtime, the frames of the `textLabel` and `rightView` seem to be set correctly, but the frame of the `tooltipView` is set to `CGRectZero`, and none of the three views appear on screen.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I've even tried removing the `textLabel` and `rightView` entirely, so just a plain UIView with leading, trailing, bottom, and height constraints. Nothing is ambiguous, but the frame of the view is still `CGRectZero`.

Comment: Are you not getting some warning in debugger window something like "not able to simultaneously satisfy constraints......" and "...will try to render after breaking constraint..."? If so, please confirm.

Comment: @Gandalf No, I've checked to make sure that the layout is not ambiguous, and the layout is not over-constrained (the layout system is not logging anything).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @matt, I appreciate it! The idea is to have a framework for any view controller in the app to display a tooltip if needed, and the tooltip can animate in various ways depending on the situation (could fade in, could slide in, could fade out, could slide out). Using a view controller along with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning seemed like the logical way to do this, but let me know if you disagree!

Comment: @matt I like the pattern used here: http://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/. The benefits of the animation encapsulation to me outweigh the "heavyweightedness" of using a view controller (which I don't see as heavyweight in this case unless you can prove that there's a significant performance impact).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the solution was simply to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in the initializer of `TooltipView` rather than overriding the method. This caused the view to appear correctly. h/t to Aaron Thompson (https://twitter.com/aaptho/status/612815498661773312).

Comment: That is just...what the fu...grrr. Worst part is, I swear I had already tried this yesterday.

Comment: Actually, _why_ does this even fix it? If the autoresizing mask was really being translated into constraints, there should have been conflicts!

Comment: Oh, because it's a _property_, and overriding the getter doesn't change the ivar, and whatever's checking it inside of UIKit is looking directly at the ivar. That's a little pothole in auto layout there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a constraint relating `textLabel` and `rightView`. Looking at your `-updateConstraints` implementation, I think the final constraints can be expressed by:

```
V:|-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-[textLabel]-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-|
V:|-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-[rightView]-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-|
H:|-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-[textLabel]
H:[rightView]-kSubviewToSuperviewSpacing-|
```

If you add a constraint relation inside you `if (self.rightView)` as:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textLabel
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.rightView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                                      constant: kTextLabelToRightViewHorizontalSpacing]];
```

And then add and `else` clause:

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[textLabel]-subviewToSuperviewSpacing-|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:metricsDictionary
                                                               views:viewsDictionary]];
```

You'll have enough constraints to unambiguously define the layout. That should trigger the constraint based auto-sizing when in the superview.

If that doesn't work you should look at overriding the `-intrinsicContentSize` method and return the intrinsicContentSize's of `textLabel` and `rightView` plus their padding. You'll need to call `-invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` in `-setRightView:` for it to work correctly.

As a minor point, you're not clearing any constraints in `-updateConstraints`, so on an constraint updating pass that calls this view, you'll get double constraints. You might want to move some of the constraint creation into `-init` and then only add/remove the `textLabel` and `rightView` relation in `-updateConstraints` as needed.

Comment: Scott, I followed all of the advice here, and the `tooltipView`'s frame is still set to `CGRectZero` when I use the view inspector at runtime. Of note, my view's layout was not ambiguous before or after adding the constraint between the `textLabel` and `rightView`. I also tried getting rid of the `TooltipViewController` entirely and just directly adding the `tooltipView` as a subview, but no dice

Comment: The intrinsic content size constraints are also overridden when I override the method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058590/what-are-gray-constraints-in-xcode-view-hierarchy-debug-view for context